# What does Dividend 165% mean in stock market?

Tags: stocks, dividends, stock-dividend

I am from India and new to share market. When I was doing some research to find which share to buy, I found one share(of Punjab National Bank) listed with 165% dividend percentage. The same percentage is given in multiple websites.

As far as I understood Dividend percentage is (dividend amount/price per share)*100. So div percent of 165% doesn't make any sense.

Please help me if I am missing out something. Here are the links

- [link1](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/punjab-national-bank/infocompanydividends/companyid-11585.cms)
- [link2](http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/banks-public-sector/punjabnationalbank/PNB05)

Comment: In your definition, the "dividend amount" is usually the *historical* value from the last *actual* dividend payment, but the "price per share" is the *current* share price. If something happens to the company that makes the share price collapse, this "historical dividend yield" can exceed 100%, but in that situation it would be foolish for an investor to expect the *next* dividend payment would be as big as to the *last* one. (Peter K's answer is correct - this is just a comment on the OP's phrase "165% doesn't make sense").

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Do not confuse the DIV (%) value and the dividend yield.](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/111314/what-difference-between-dividend-yield-and-dividend-payout-ratio.asp)

[As you can see from this page](http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/banks-public-sector/punjabnationalbank/PNB05), the DIV (%) is, as you say, 165%.  However, the dividend yield is 3.73% at the time of writing.

As the Investopedia page referenced above says:

> The payout ratio is calculated as follows: Annual Dividends per Share / Earnings per Share.

which means that the dividends being paid out are more than the earnings of the company:

> In extreme cases, dividend payout ratios exceed 100%, meaning more dividends were paid out than there were profits that year. Significantly high ratios are unsustainable.

[image]

Comment: Pls check if I got that right: If I've 1000 in shares with a DIV of 5%, I'd get 50. Now if the company makes surplus and decides to pay a higher DIV this year, let's say 7.5% instead of 5%.
I'd then receive 75 instead of 50, which would mean the DIV ratio is 150%? Or on the other site, if the company is struggling and reduces payout to 3% instead of 5%, the DIV ratio is 60%?

Comment: @Sempie DIV says **nothing** about how much you get. It just tells you how much the company pays out *relative* to how much it made. You would *not* get 50 from a DIV of 5% without several other numbers being right.

Comment: Calling the [payout ratio](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/payoutratio.asp) "DIV (%)" sure is confusing.

Comment: @Zenadix : You're not wrong! :-)